# onclick event on asp.net not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" href="#MainContent_tabs1"   OnClientClick="alert('Your changes will be saved.')" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click1">General Info</asp:LinkButton></li>

protected void LinkButton1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        SaveGeneralInfo();
        //alert
    }
    else
    {
        alert.Show("Missing required field(s).");
    }
}
```

Comment: SaveGeneral Info method calls to the database. This call is not working, any help on this matter is appraciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `href="#MainContent_tabs1"`. `href` is not a valid property of `LinkButton`. And it interferes with the PostBack.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="alert('Your changes will be saved.');" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">General Info</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I have differnet buttons on aspx page. Once I click on any of the tab i need to save the value. here is a code: <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" href="#MainContent_tabs1"   OnClientClick="alert('Your changes will be saved.')" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click1">General Info</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" href="#MainContent_tabs2"   OnClientClick="alert('Your changes will be saved.')" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click1">Position Vacancies</asp:LinkButton></li>

Comment: I need to have href  for liinking to another button, right?

Comment: It does not work that way. Either use normal links and save with Ajax or set the correct tab when PostBack has finished.